# error: illegal character: '\ufeff' in java

Tags: java, compilation, ubuntu-16.04

Got this error when compiled java code in ubuntu.

![Got this error][1]

> ```
> error: illegal character: '\ufeff'
> ```

```
import java.net.*;
^
```

> ```
> error: class, interface, or enum expected
> ```

```
import java.net.*;
        ^
```

Comment: Looks like a UTF-8 BOM (Byte Order Marker) at the start of the file.  That should not be there, just remove it.

Comment: How to remove that ?

Comment: How did you create the file? Use an editor that does not add the BOM, or configure your editor to not add the BOM when editing UTF-8

Answer (score 19):

As [Jim Garrison](https://stackoverflow.com/q/45697794/1708751#comment78353989_45697794) pointed out, you probably have a [Byte Order Marker (BOM)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Byte_order_mark) at the start of the file. Use an editor that can view all non-printable characters and remove it.

Alternatively, you can use [sed](https://linux.die.net/man/1/sed) to remove it:

```
sed '1s/^.//' infile >> outfile
```

Comment: Or in vim `:set nobomb` `:wq`

Comment: `:x ` is shorter than `:wq`. :)

Comment: if you use intellij right click on file and choose "Remove BOM"

Answer (score 16):

If you are using IntelliJ, right click on the class file and select 'Remove BOM'.
That should remove the BOM at the start.

Comment: It's strange but sometimes it doesn't work at first so I have first to add BOM and then remove BOM

Comment: Had the same issue with `netlify.toml` causing a config parsing error on Netlify. This worked, thanks.

Answer (score 11):

In case your are working on Windows O.S. and use Eclipse (which don't have the functionality to remove the BOM from the file), just open the file in Notepad++ and in the encoding menu, select "UTF-8", then save the file.

Comment: It is quite possible in eclipse: Just change the encoding of the file to iso (Right click on file - > Properties) and delete the first three BOM characters, save file and reopen it.

Answer (score 2):

I am using **clean and modern looking UI** in intellij, I removed BOM by clicking on the bottom right encoding which in my case was **UTF-8**, and a panel displaying the file encoding list appears, allowing me to easily choose the **remove BOM** option and proceed with the removal.

Answer (score 1):

IF you get java: illegal character: '\ufeff' error in java you must remove BOM on the right bottom of IDE Look bottom and right, click UTF-8 and remove BOM [click for image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Kfrlq.png)

Answer (score 0):

Use another editor because it seems to be an eclipse UTF-8-BOM problem.
Convert the UTF type UTF-8.

And also I note that ; First it doesn't work for me and I convert the type ANSI and after convert type to UTF-8 format. It can be a another alternative solution for you

Answer (score 0):

downloading models from https://codebeautify.org/json-to-java-converter is causing such problems.

create new file and copy/paste all data from the downloaded file.